# Lateinit property has not been initialized (Android, Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm currently working with a room database in my journal app. However, whenever I try to insert a new entry into my app without changing the bitmap variable by picking an image, my app crashes and displays this error.

```
2020-12-24 22:44:35.296 31023-31023/com.google.gradient.red E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.google.gradient.red, PID: 31023
    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property bitmap has not been initialized
        at com.google.gradient.red.fragments.add.addFragment.insertDataToDb(AddFragment.kt:132)
        at com.google.gradient.red.fragments.add.addFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(AddFragment.kt:111)
```

Here is my code:

```kotlin
// I make my bitmap variable
lateinit var bitmap: Bitmap

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
    }
```

Line 111 is when I call my `insertDataToDb()` function, and line 132 is in `newData` where I'm trying to insert my bitmap variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property bitmap has not been initialized`

The error message is clear. You've defined a `lateinit` field but never initialized it.
In your code here:

```kotlin
// I make my bitmap variable
lateinit var bitmap: Bitmap

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
}
```

You're defining a `lateinit var` called `bitmap`. So, since you used the keyword `lateinit`, you definitely should initialize it somewhere. Which, I guess, is what you were trying to do in the `onAttach` method. However, you're defining a new "local" variable instead of initializing the original one. So, remove the `onAttach` method and change this:

```kotlin
lateinit var bitmap: Bitmap
```

To this:

```kotlin
var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this solved the error I was getting!
However, I realized that the error I showed here was unrelated to what I was trying to ask, so I'll edit my question to fit this answer more and leave it here.

Comment: I apologize for putting another comment here, but after trying the code without any changes (which caused some other issues) I'm getting these two errors:
`'lateinit' modifier is not allowed on properties of nullable types` and `'lateinit' modifier is not allowed on properties with initializer`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad. Just like the error message says; you cannot use nullable types and `lateinit` keyword together. So, you just need to delete the keyword `lateinit`. I'll edit my answer.