# Only show 5 dot indicators for viewpager remaining i need to hide

Tags: android, kotlin, viewpagerindicator

I added dot indicators for viewpager, In that viewpages when I have 15 datas, dot indicators also 15 dots showing. but I don't want that I need to show only 5 dot indicators eventhough I'm having 20 datas in my view pager

```
 private fun setUpTabs(binding: FragmentHomeBinding, viewpager: ViewPagerAdapter) {
    binding.viewPagerNews.adapter = viewpager
    binding.indicatorContainer.setViewPager(binding.viewPagerNews)
}
```

[image]
I need to show like this

[image]
I'm getting like this

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ScrollingPagerIndicator](https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/ScrollingPagerIndicator) to show only 5 dots at a time and make it scrollable at user swipe through pages.

Dependency

```
implementation "ru.tinkoff.scrollingpagerindicator:scrollingpagerindicator:1.2.0"
```

Layout

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ru.tinkoff.scrollingpagerindicator.ScrollingPagerIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:spi_dotColor="@color/red"               // unselected dot color
    app:spi_dotSelectedColor="@color/teal_200"  // selected dot color
    app:spi_visibleDotCount="5"                 // max dot to be visible
    app:spi_dotSize="5dp"                       // dot sizes
     />
```

Attach indicator to your `Viewpager`

```
ViewPager pager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(new DemoPagerAdapter());
ScaledDotsIndicator indicator = findViewById(R.id.indicator);
indicator.attachToPager(pager);
```

You can also use this with `ViewPager2` or `RecyclerView`.

Setup ViewPager2 with indicator

```
    ViewPager2 pager2 = findViewById(R.id.pager2);
    DemoRecyclerViewAdapter pagerAdapter2 = new DemoRecyclerViewAdapter();
    pager2.setAdapter(pagerAdapter2);

    ScrollingPagerIndicator pagerIndicator2 = findViewById(R.id.pager_indicator2);
    pagerIndicator2.attachToPager(pager2);
```

[image]

Comment: How can i use this with viewpager 2 can you please help me to solve...because I'm getting  error on this attachToPager line   "  binding.invitesViewpage.adapter = sliderAdapter
        binding.indicatorsContainer.attachToPager(binding.invitesViewpage)"

Comment: I have added the code to attach to `viewpager2`. You can also look into [demo given](https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/ScrollingPagerIndicator/tree/master/demo)

Comment: If there is still an issue, please share the error.

Comment: ya, I just check it, I tried both attachToPager and attachtoRecyclerView, for these I'm getting this error "Cannot access class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies"  "Cannot access class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies"

Comment: Tring using this [`indicator.attachToRecyclerView(viewPager2.getChildAt(0) as RecyclerView)`](https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/ScrollingPagerIndicator/issues/23) , also it seems latest version is 1.2.0.

Comment: Still it showing error  Type mismatch.
Required:
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
Found:
androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager  I added like this binding.indicatorsContainer.attachToPager(viewPager2.getChildAt(0) as ViewPager)

Comment: What's the version you are using , this issue seems to be fixed in 1.2.0 version , or you need to your `attachToRecyclerView` method

Comment: 1.2.0 means is it recycler version?

Comment: I'm using androix but it is asking me android support

Comment: `scrollingpagerindicator:scrollingpagerindicator` version 1.2.0  , this version supports androidx and viewpager2, previous version was not supported for androidx, that's why it was giving error. I have updated my answer

Comment: ok I'll change to 1.2.0 version

Comment: after i changed  I'm getting this error :-  lateinit property sliderAdapter has not been initialized

Comment: Have the initialised your adapter? You need to attach your code to look for this error.

Comment: yes I installed.

Comment: Can't able to upload my full code heree.. I'm getting this issue  It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: `yes I installed. ` - Didn't get your point , Also could please move these comments to the chat.

Comment: You don't to post your full code, just post code where you initialize and use your adapter ,/. Also you can look into this answer also , it has same error as your - [lateinit not initilized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65445137/lateinit-property-has-not-been-initialized-android-kotlin)

Comment: Can you please say how to change selected and unselected colors  I added these lines for that,  but it is not setted app:ci_drawable="@drawable/selected"
                        app:ci_drawable_unselected="@drawable/unselected"

Comment: I'm not sure where you got these key names `app:ci_drawable` , Anyways I have edited the answer to color changes .

Comment: Hi, How can I use the drawable resource instead of circle dot?.

Comment: @GeetaGupta , it supports drawable for first and last dots via `spi_firstDotDrawable` and `spi_lastDotDrawable`. To change all circle dots you need to modify library according to your requirement.